# When open & write text in python, why my contents are gone

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
inputFile = open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt', "r") 
exportFile = open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt', "w")
for line in inputFile:
    s = list(line, sep = '\t')
    if s[1] < 0:
        s[1] += 360
    s[0] *= 0.01
    t = '\t'
    new_line = t.join(s)
    exportFile.write(new_line) 
inputFile.close()
exportFile.close()
```

[It was the file but now it's gone away.
Of course, I have made back-up file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXgEc.png)

Comment: try without closing the file, and what file has gone?

Comment: try using the 'a' for append option when opening the file

Comment: Are you reading and writing to the same file? I can see both the names are same.

Answer (score 0):

your input and output file are the same.

```
inputFile = open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt', "r") 
exportFile = open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt', "w")
```

you can't write to the output while you are still reading the same file.

Easiert solution: Write the output into a different file. If successful, delete the input file and rename the output file to the name of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the same files and writing to it as well. What you can do is read all the lines, manipulate it and the write back to the same file once complete reading is done as the below code:

```
inputFile = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt'
exportFile = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/dihedral/6.txt'
new_lines = []
with open(inputFile, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        s = list(line, sep = '\t')
        if s[1] < 0:
            s[1] += 360
        s[0] *= 0.01
        new_lines.append('\t'.join(s))

with open(expotFile, 'w') as fq:
    fq.write('\n'.join(new_lines))
```